# Ninject Scope and System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, ninject, unit-of-work

How to invoke a new Ninject context on a Timer task?
Having a hard time configuring ninject scope to unitofwork. If I set as InRequestScope() it doesn't work on non request tasks. So I set up like below so that I can get InThreadScope for tasks:

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<myEntities>().InScope(ctx => HttpContext.Current ?? StandardScopeCallbacks.Thread(ctx));
```

But that way, when I set up a timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer(_ => DelayedDisconnect(chatUser.User.AuthorizationId), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

the dbContext doesn't refresh with the new database values.

```
public void DelayedDisconnect(string authorizationId)
    {
        var myChatUser = GetChatUserByClaimedIdentifier(authorizationId);

        if (!myChatUser.ChatClients.Any()) // old state (doesn't reflect database changes from 10 seconds ago).
```

So...How to invoke a new Ninject "context" to reflect current state / db values?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't run background tasks in an ASP.NET application. Write a service to do this. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

By using a windows service it gets really easy. Setup a timer that requests a `SomeProcessor` that does all the work from the kernel. Now you can use the NamedScope extension and define that the processor is the scope for some objects like the UoW

```
kernel.Bind<SomeProcessor>().ToSelf().DefinesNamedScope("Processor");
kernel.Bind<IUoW>().To<UoW>().InNamedScope("Processor");
```

Comment: Thanks Remo for the quick response. But in this case it's not a recurrent independent task...it's actualy a single delayed task that get called from the web app when the client closes the browser window (using SignalR for that). Do you still think that a windows service would be best for that? In that case how would I call the service from the web app?