# NamedScopes Ninject bindings and async (threading)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

My project is structured by services and repositories (all repositories share the db context). In one of my service layers, I have an asynchronous method that writes to the database using a repository. The web request will finish and dispose of the context before this method can get to use it. I tried to understand [NamedScopes](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/how-to-use-the-additional-ninject-scopes-of-namedscope/) as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669539/400861). I still can't seem to understand how to implement it. I'll show how my project is structured and hope someone can help me at the code level.

**Bindings**

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //dbcontext
        kernel.Bind<EntityDatabaseContext>().ToMethod(context => new EntityDatabaseContext()).InRequestScope();

        //unit of work
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();

        //repositories
        kernel.Bind<IRepository<Account>>().To<Repository<Account>>().InRequestScope();

        //services
        kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<AuthenticationService>().InRequestScope();
    }
```

**AuthenticationService uses constructor injection**

```
public AuthenticationService(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRepository<Account> accountRepository){}
```

**A method inside my AuthenticationService**

```
    //this is a background process
    public Task SomeMethodAsync(string text)
    {
        //spin it off into a new task
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod(text));
    }
```

`SomeMethod` makes use of `accountRepository`. Please tell me if anymore information is needed. Please help me with the threading issue, if NamedScopes is the solution, how do I implement it in my case?

Basically, a background process is being executed and it is using a context that is being disposed of by ninject due to the request scope.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you want to achieve? Do you simply want to load some data in your method SomeMethodAsync asynchronously or do you want to background process some information in a job like fashion?
One major problem in your design is, that your are starting directly a new task in SomeMethodAsync. Starting a new task gives no promise about the task execution. The tasks might be executed after your request has ended and then ninject will already have disposed in request scope. If you use AsyncController the task should be registered on it. But the API should not start it

Comment: @DanielMarbach That is my problem, the task may be executed after the request ends and ninject disposes of the context. I need to tell ninject to wait. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: @DanielMarbach what do you mean the API should not start it?

Comment: About starting: I got that wrong. TPL guidelines state that you MUST start the task. So that one is fine. In my point of view this problem is not related to ninject. You need to use AsyncController and do the asynchronous operation with the async controller. Then it should work.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want that the web request is completed immediately after the task is started or do you want that the request waits for some result of the task so that you can return some information from that result?

Comment: @RemoGloor I do not want to return anything from the task, I think the name is a background task. I want to end the web request immediately after executed.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444454/ninject-scope-and-system-threading-timer/11446626#11446626 (Cant be bothered to see if its a dup, in which case Remo's fantastic answer should move over to the first instance of this question and this one vtc'd - @Remo Gloor?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be aware that running background threads can cause you many problems. IIS can decide to recycle the app pool at any time which will terminate your thread immediately (or it doesn't execute in some cases at all) leaving your application in an inconsistent state.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

The easiest and least error prone wayto run asyncronous operations is to implement a windows service and delegate those async operations to the windows service e.g. using MSMQ.

If you still want to go the hard way then read about `HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject` and `IRegisteredObject` to prevent these inconsistent situations.

The Ninject part is quite easy. Just create some job processor class e.g. `MyJobProcessor` taking all required dependencies to execute the task. It should implement `INotifyWhenDisposed`. The easiest way to do so is to derive from `DisposeNotifyingObject`.

```
public class MyJobProcessor : DisposeNotifyingObject, IRegisteredObject
{
    public void Execute() { ... }
    public void Stop(bool immediate) { ... }
}
```

Inject this processor to the controller and let the Task start it and dispose it when it has finished its work.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            processor.Execute(); 
        } 
        finally 
        { 
            processor.Dispose); 
        }
    });
```

Specify that it is the scope for its dependencies.

```
Bind<MyJobProcessor>().ToSelf().Named("MyJobProcessor").DefinesNamedScope("MyJobProcessorScope");
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WhenAnyAnchestorNamed("MyJobProcessor").InNamedScope("MyJobProcessorScope");
```

Comment: Thank you, in regards to using a windows service, would it be suitable for situations like logging (user logs in, I log it) or sending emails (templating)? These behaviors makes the action takes longer to return which is why I'd like them in a background task.

Comment: @Lolcoder The question is if you can afford loosing this data. E.g. If the server recycles due some error can you afford not having the log? Or can you live with a situation where the EMail is not sent? Also logging and sending emails usually does not need dependencies. You should also check how much performance you really gain. Creating and starting a Task takes some time as well.

Comment: If either of those were done synchronously in the request and the pool recycled wouldn't they fail too?